# PHP - check if Image/Video/Object seen

Tags: php

Can I check if lets say an image in index.php is seen by user? I do not only want to know if page is visited, but also user scrolled down the page and this image is displayed or not.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?  If your desired image is in fixed place, you could trigger an AJAX request to your server, once a certain amount of scrolling has been made.

Comment: you can't track user interactions with PHP, that would need a client side technology like JavaScript.

Comment: thank you, but i know that, but the problem is, page is dynamic, and content can be changed so, i cannot give any static value to AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an easy thing to do.
You need to check is if user scrolled down to the position of element, and then, if true, make an AJAX call to PHP that will save this information into the database.

Most accurate way to do this is by using jQuery [.scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) to see how far user scrolled down and compare it with [.offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).

Keep in mind though that it's not 100% accurate. It should be good enough for most of layouts and most of images, however small pictures placed in layouts that use lot of paddings will most likely return incorrect results (either indicating that image was viewed before it actually was, or after, assuming you scroll down to see it).

If I were you - I'd try to avoid this functionality. ;) It's just too prone to errors that you can't really do anything about.

Answer (score 0):

You'll surely need Javascript to do that. With PHP you can only check if a page has been visited. I'd check how much a user has scrolled the page with Javascript based on where the pic is shown in the page. But the truth is that you can't rely on that check, anything client side can be faked quite easily.